# Unitary operator in von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $R\subseteq B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra, and $U\in R$ be unitary. Prove that there is a self adjoint operator $A\in R$ such that $||A||\leq \pi$, and $U=\exp(iA)$ . Any idea how to start! Thank you

Comment: That's by the Borel functional calculus for normal elements (also called $L^\infty$ functional calculus). A reason in itself to introduce and study von Neumann algebras. [See here, Theorem 6](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/261ynotes/lecture17.pdf), for a statement of the theorem. The principal branch of $\log$ is defined on the spectrum of $u$, except maybe at $-1$. Extend it by whatever at this point. It will still be $L^\infty$. So $\frac{1}{i}\log u$ is defined and does what you need.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that as a consequence of this powerful functional calculus, every element has a polar decomposition within the von Neumann algebra. Unlike in $C^*$-algebras, where we only have continuous functional calculus, so that we can't always get the unitary part.

Comment: @julien; Do I have to take $f(\lambda) = log \lambda$ ?

Comment: If you want $A=f(U)$  with th required conditions, you must take $f(\lambda)=-i\log\lambda$ (up to a measure $0$ set), where $\log$ is the principal branch of the complex logarithm.

Comment: @julien Why don't you post your comment as answer?

Comment: @Norbert Done, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $U$ is a normal operator in $R$, we can use the $L^\infty$ functional calculus which yields an isometric $R$-valued *-homomorphism
$$
L^\infty(\sigma(U))\longrightarrow R\qquad f\longmapsto f(U).
$$
The principal branch of the complex logarithm $\log$ induces a function of $L^\infty(\sigma(U))$ on the spectrum of $U$, extended by $0$ if you want at $-1$. So 
$$
A:=-i\log U
$$
defines a bounded operator, element of $R$. Now let us use the properties of the functional calculus. Note that the spectrum of $U$ is contained in the unit circle.

1- Since $\log(\overline{z})=-\log z$ on the unit circle and $g(z)=\overline{\log \overline{z}}=\log z$ everywhere, we have $(\log U)^*=g(U^*)=\log U^*=-\log U$. Hence $A^*=(-i\log U)^*=i(\log U)^*=-i\log U=A$. That is $A$ is hermitian.

2- Since $e^{i(-i\log z)}=z$ a.e., we have $e^{iA}=U$ by composition of the functional calculus of $A$ and $U$.

3- Since $-i\log z \in (-\pi,\pi]$ for every $z$ on the unit circle, we see that $\|A\|=\sup_{\sigma(U)}|-i\log z|\leq \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A = f(U)$ for a certain function $f$.